# python travers combobox drop down

Tags: python, combobox, bind

I'm using python3.7.
I'm using a tkinter combo box. I'd like to trigger an event WITHOUT clicking the pop up widget associated with the combo box. As the user keys up and down through the popup, additional information is displayed for the highlighted item. Allowing the user to browse the entries prior to selecting an item.

Comment: "_additional information is displayed for the highlighted item_" you can use `Pmw` module which has balloon widget for this and you can do keybinding to it too i guess, if this is what you want, let me know :D Please do include some code of your combobox and what you have so far

Comment: thanks for your reply!  When I actually select the item, it displays the details in a text box...and I think i'd want the same behavior. any more ideas would be welcome. Do you still want to see some of my code? Wasn't sure that it was necessary since I'm not describing a bug ...but would be happy to.

Comment: Yes `Pmw` is the easiest way there, unless you want to create a custom class for the tooltip. Ill add an answer on how to use `Pmw` if you want so :D

Comment: sure. it's worth a look!